# Where is routing table stored internally in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, linux-kernel, route

When I execute `route -n`, from where exactly (from which `struct`s) is the information displayed retrieved?

I tried executing `strace route -n` but I didn't help me finding the right place it's stored.

Comment: Please go through this http://superuser.com/questions/322717/how-does-route-n-work-in-linux

Comment: It's stored in memory. Are you looking for the memory address it's at?

Comment: @Bandrami I would like to see what `struct` is responsible for holding the information.

Comment: For anyone looking for the file on disk, it's either built from whatever the DHCP server gives out, or from what can be found in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-${DEV}` in simple cases and/or from what can be found in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-${DEV}` in more convoluted cases (case of Red Hat / CentOS 7). The latter file contains the output of `ip -r`. See [Add a Static Route on CentOS](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redhat-centos-fedora-linux-static-routing/).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `route` or the `ip` utility get their information from a pseudo filesystem called `procfs`. It is normally mounted under `/proc`. There is a file called `/proc/net/route`, where you can see the kernel's IP routing table. You can print the routing table with `cat` instead, but the route utility formats the output human readable, because the IP adresses are stored in hex.

That file is not just a normal file. It is always generated at exactly the moment when opening it with an attempt to read, as all files in the proc filesystem.

I you are interessted how that file is written, then you need to look at the kernel sources:
That [function](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/fib_trie.c#L2413) outputs the routeing table. You see at [line 2510](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v3.17/net/ipv4/fib_trie.c#L2510), the header of the routing table is printed. The routing table appears to be mostly in the struct `fib_info` that is defined in the header file [ip_fib.h, line 98](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/net/ip_fib.h#L98).