# How to get default gateway if netstat/ifconfig and ip are not available?

Tags: linux, ip

So I have a centos or ubuntu docker container and discovered that there are no `ip`, `netstat` to `ifconfig`. I would not like to install any additional packages. Is there any way to get default gateway if none of mentioned commands are available?

PS I need default gateway in order to know how can I access docker host from container.

Comment: Just discovered that I can get container ip with `hostname -i'. I can easily guess the default gateway until I have more than 254 containers running.

Comment: See below stackexchange link for detailed answer [Where is routing table stored internally in the Linux kernel?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204260/where-is-routing-table-stored-internally-in-the-linux-kernel)

Answer (score 2):

As @dirkt mentioned, the default routing table is stored as text in `/proc/net/route` on any modern Linux system, but unfortunately the IP addresses are stored in (reversed) hex. With a little bash hacking and an assist from `awk` and `sed` we can turn this into a human readable ip address:

```bsh
for i in $(echo "$(< /proc/net/route | head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $3}')" | sed -E 's/(..)(..)(..)(..)/\4 \3 \2 \1/' ) ; do printf "%d." $((16#$i)); done | sed 's/.$//'
```

Here's the same idea in a more readable (and multi-line) version:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
get-default-gateway() {
  default_route_ip="$(< /proc/net/route | head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $3}')"

  hex-ip-to-dec-ip "$default_route_ip"
}

hex-ip-to-dec-ip() {
  local hex_ip="$1" 
  for i in $(echo "$hex_ip" | sed -E 's/(..)(..)(..)(..)/\4 \3 \2 \1/' ) ; do 
    printf "%d." $((16#$i));
  done | sed 's/.$//' 
}

get-default-gateway
```

Comment: To go the other way (and make it a bit shorter), this one-liner does the same thing: `</proc/net/route awk 'NR==2 {print $3}' | sed -E 's/(..)/\\1 /g' | if read a b c d; then printf '%d.%d.%d.%d' 0x$d 0x$c 0x$b 0x$a; fi`

Answer (score 1):

`cat /proc/net/route` gives you the complete routing table including default gateway, just like `ip route`. IP addresses are in hex and byte reversed, though.

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS, you can get the Default Gateway details from ***/etc/sysconfig/network*** file

Comment: Hehe. All I see in this file in centos container is: `# Created by anaconda`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *route* command:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1
```

Comment: It's fairly likely that `route` will also be unavailable when there's no `ifconfig` or `ip`.